# Change column type of a grid dynamically

Tags: grid, dhtmlx, column-types

Hi im working with dhtmlx and I have a gridview, i want that the column type change sometimes in differents rows

heres is the code where i load the grid

```
                    mygrid = new dhtmlXGridObject('gridbox');
                    mygrid.imgURL = "/dhtmlxGrid/sources/imgs/";
                    mygrid.setHeader("Tipo,Actividad,Cantidad", null, ["text-align:center;","text-align:center;","text-align:center;","text-align:center;"]);
                    mygrid.attachHeader("#numeric_filter,#text_filter,#text_filter,#numeric_filter");
                    mygrid.setSkin("dhx_web");
                    mygrid.setInitWidths("100,200,300,75")
                    mygrid.setColTypes("coro,txttxt,dyn");
                    mygrid.setColAlign("left,left,right");
                    mygrid.setColSorting("str,str,int");
                    mygrid.enableBlockSelection();
                    mygrid.enableMultiline(true);
                    mygrid.init();
```

and here is where i wanna change the column type

```
function agre_regi()
```

{

```
if(document.getElementById("cmbCata_repo").value == 5 || document.getElementById("cmbCata_repo").value == 6)
{
        mygrid.addRow(mygrid.getRowsNum()+1,[document.getElementById('cmbCata_repo').value,document.getElementById('txtCausas').value,document.getElementById('txtCantidad').value]);           
}else
{
        mygrid.addRow(mygrid.getRowsNum()+1,[document.getElementById('cmbCata_repo').value,cmbActividad.getSelectedText(),document.getElementById('txtCantidad').value]);
}
```

}

if you get inside of the first if i wanna do mygrid.setColTypes("coro,txttxt,dyn")
else
mygrid.setColTypes("coro,coro,dyn")

Answer (score 1):

You may change the type of any cell in your grid dynamically using the setCellExcelltype() method:
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/api__dhtmlxgrid_setcellexcelltype.html